# Keyboard layout won't reset on new windows - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

I have setup the options of Keyboard layout as shown in the attached picture. Nevertheless, sometimes when I write on my browser in Arabic or German, and after that I start a terminal (or any program for that purpose), the keyboard layout remains Arabic or German, which could be really really annoying and time wasting before realizing that the layout wasn't reset!

Anyone knows how to really get the default layout (English) to start with every new window?

Thank you for any efforts.

[image]

Comment: I see that someone voted down this question, which I don't understand at all. To me the question is crystal clear. OTOH I think you have encountered a bug with no easy workaround. See for example https://launchpad.net/bugs/943267

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Pretty weird... the bug is there in that link since Ubuntu 11.10... I wonder why Ubuntu crew hasn't managed to fix it.